# How do you pass a property to a command line gradle task?

Tags: gradle

I'm new to Gradle and having issues passing a property to a command line task. When I attempt to execute this task by executing the command `./gradlew buildDocker -Pgcpproject=my-cool-project`, I receive the following error:

```
Could not get unknown property 'gcpproject' for task ':buildDocker' of 
type org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.
```

This is the task that as I wrote it:

```
task buildDocker(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'sh', "./scripts/buildDockerImage.sh", "${gcpproject}"
}
```

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening? Thank you for reading.

Comment: Why do you need the ${ }  around the gcpproject?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_system_properties) you should be able to use

`task buildDocker(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'sh', "./scripts/buildDockerImage.sh", gcpproject
 }`